# The Visual Studio Bitbucket extension is not pulling changes from repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

My partner has set up a Bitbucket repo. I have setup the Bitbucket extension for Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

When I PULL or SYNC it only is bringing in the local code and not the changes from the repo.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: but code on the server is ahead of local?

Comment: Yes, the code on the server is newer than local.

Comment: how you do sync?

Comment: Double-click on the top line and select sync

Comment: after this you go to Synchronization and press Sync again?